# Add columns dynamically to Cassandra from Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, ddl, cql

I am trying to add new columns dynamically from Spring Boot application. Let us say, each time an event e occurs, I want to add a column into a Cassandra table with a well defined column-name and type. I have tried this code:

```
    @Query("alter table attributes.attributedata add ?0 ?1")
    public void addColumn(String columnName, String dataType);
```

Error Log:

```
    org.springframework.cassandra.support.exception.CassandraQuerySyntaxException: line 1:41 no viable alternative at input 'gac5' (alter table attributes.attributedata add ['gac]...); nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:41 no viable alternative at input 'gac5' (alter table attributes.attributedata add ['gac]...)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.support.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:132)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(CqlTemplate.java:946)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.translateExceptionIfPossible(CqlTemplate.java:930)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.translateExceptionIfPossible(CqlTemplate.java:912)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:278)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:559)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:549)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:485)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:510)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:505)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.selectOne(CassandraTemplate.java:638)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.selectOne(CassandraTemplate.java:509)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.execute(CassandraQueryExecution.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryExecution$ResultProcessingExecution.execute(CassandraQueryExecution.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.AbstractCassandraQuery.execute(AbstractCassandraQuery.java:113)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
```

I have also tried to store the entire query into a string and then directly place the string into value such that
`@Query(value="?0")`
but that does not work either.

This code works perfectly fine. If the values obtained from the function are not enclosed within single inverted commas, the code would work.

```
    @Query("alter table attributes.attributedata add dummy text")
    public void addColumn(String columnName, String dataType);
```

Is there any way this could work? Please suggest the possible alternatives.

Comment: Are you able to use the schemabuilder within the driver : https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.11/manual/query_builder/schema/ ?

Comment: Hi @Andrew I am not able to import the package as my app is dependent on another Spring Boot app for packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cluster object can be created as shown in the code, followed by the session object on which the query is executed. The name and type of the column to be added are passed as parameters.

```
   public void addColumn(String columnName, String columnType){

      //Query
      String query = "ALTER TABLE keyspace.tablename ADD " + columnName + " " + columnType;

      //Creating Cluster object
      Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
   
      //Creating Session object
      Session session = cluster.connect();
 
      //Executing the query
      session.execute(query);
 
      System.out.println("Column added");
   }
```

In order to optimize the code, we can create the session object only once during the application startup. The implementation for such scenario is given below:

```
   private Session session;

   @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
   private void createSessionObject(){
      //Creating Cluster object
      Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
   
      //Creating Session object
      Session session = cluster.connect();
   }

   public void addColumn(String columnName, String columnType){

      //Query
      String query = "ALTER TABLE keyspace.tablename ADD " + columnName + " " + columnType;

      if(session == null){
         createSessionObject();
      }
 
      //Executing the query
      session.execute(query);
 
      System.out.println("Column added");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using CONCAT

```
@Query("alter table attributes.attributedata add CONCAT('%',:columnNameDataType,'%')")
public void addColumn(String columnNameDataType);
```

Check this [link](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/string#CONCAT___String_Concatenation)